# IE8 Javascript Performance monitoring tool

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer-8, performance-testing

Anyone know of a good javascript performance tool?  I have a javascript heavy page that runs fine in chrome but is very slow in IE.

I'd like to poke around and see what portions of my javascript may be slowing it down.

Comment: IE8 is pants for JavaScript, but there's nothing we can do about that. I read somewhere that adding more `$(document).ready( ... )` functions exponentially slows down the page, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynatrace AJAX Edition is what you want, though it might take a little while to get used to it.

Dynatrace have some good video tutorials / talks online.

http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/

It's free too

Comment: awesome,  I'm looking for something beyond IE's tools, something like this is what I was hoping for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know that IE9 has a script profiler built-in to the dev tools (press F12 to access). I know IE8 has the same tools, but unsure if it has the profiler. If it doesn't have the profiler, you could always use IE9 placed into IE8 browser mode